# Which problems domains are more suited  to functional programming solutions

Tags: functional-programming

Which problems domains are more suited to functional programming solutions and why? Can anyone provide any examples?

**EDIT** Just to clarify, I'm not asking for a list of problems. I want to know what **type** of problems are best suited to functional solutions. For example I have heard financial problems are solved well with functional programming.

Comment: "List of" questions where each answer is equally valid aren't suited to the Stack Exchange format. What specific problem are you trying to solve here?

Comment: Related: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/76801/why-functional-programming, http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/76151/functional-programming-in-commercial-software, http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/10865/for-what-common-problems-is-functional-programming-not-a-good-fit

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Functional programming uses immutable datastructures and doesn't rely on mutable state, this means that the programs are easier to reason about and easier to prove for correctness.

Functional programming is easiest to use for stateless problems, e.g. programs that takes an input and generates an output without a need for side effects. Typical problem domains are compilers and stateless servers. Or libraries for calculations.

Comment: I really think this is a myth that refuses to die. Even in a pure functional language like Haskell, causing side effects isn't hard at all. The difference is that side effects are explicit in the type system. I also think that "generates an output without a need for side effects" is self-contradicting. Generating output is a side-effect. In Haskell this is done in the IO monad for example. This doesn't mean that IO is "hard" in Haskell.