# Example of where Functional Programming is Superior to Imperative or Object-Oriented Programming?

Tags: object-oriented, functional-programming, lisp, f#, imperative-programming

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Which problems domains are more suited  to functional programming solutions](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/113763/which-problems-domains-are-more-suited-to-functional-programming-solutions)

I've been reading about functional programming.  I've been using mostly C#.net recently, and I would like to know of a good real-world example of where a functional language such as Lisp or F# would be a clearly superior tool for getting a job done.

Comment: Chances are you're already using a lot of functional programming in your C# already. LINQ, essentially, *is*  a functional programming. It's up to you to decide on how relevant it is to the real world.

Comment: Strictly speaking, (Common) Lisp is not a functional language.

Answer (score 9):

I find functional languages better because they tend to demand very little ceremony for the functionality they provide. For example....let's take every number in a list of integers add one to the number, and then sum them.

In Clojure:

```
(reduce + (map inc mylist))
```

In C# (functional style):

```
result = mylist.Select(i => i + 1).Sum();
```

In C# (imperative style):

```
int sum = 0; 
foreach (int i in mylist)
{
   sum += (i + 1);
}
```

Let's look at the imperative style...we have to create a accumulator (sum), a locally scoped variable (i), and we also have to be explicit in how we enumerate our loop. What takes a single line of code, and is extremely readable in a functional language has ballooned into 5 lines of C# and it's not nearly as readable.

So after studying both imperative   and functional languages for several years, I've simply come to the conclusion that I would rather use less work to accomplish more. Since switching to Clojure for all my hobby projects I've found that I can suddenly accomplish much more with less code.

---

So back to your question, I never find myself asking "why would I use a functional language?", but instead, "why wouldn't I use a functional language?". Sometimes it requires thinking about the problem in a different way, but I find that my functional code is more concise, elegant, and readable than the code I'm forced to write in C#.

---

For context, I code in C# 8+ hours a day at work, and code around 1-2 hours in Clojure every night.

Comment: +1: I never find myself asking "why would I use a functional language?", but instead, "why wouldn't I use a functional language?"

Comment: "concise" = yes, "elegant" = maybe, "readable" = not really.

Comment: On a minor note, C# code can be just `mylist.Sum(i => i + 1);` which I dont think anyone can argue is less readable than the given Clojure version :)

Comment: @swdev well that is obviously highly subjective, and above all, mostly depending on what you're used to. If you only ever worked in C# 1.0 in all your life, then yes, a data transformation stream using LINQ will look weird, but that's only because it's new syntax and an API you haven't used before. The basic map/fold/etc operators that are popular in functional languages are as universally recognized  as `int x = 1;` is in C. What IS an objective fact though, is that the functional code ONLY describes the algorithm in terms of it's semantic components, there's little or no boilerplate.

Answer (score 2):

Functional programming is commonly used in academics. Some would argue that it is superior in teaching. It also is good for massive concurrent systems.

Most of what you're asking can be answered by several previous questions:

Lisp usages: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/794450/what-is-lisp-used-for-today-and-where-do-you-think-its-going

F# usage: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36756/f-what-are-you-using-it-for

Haskell usage: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1604790/what-is-haskell-actually-useful-for

Erlang usage: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1636455/where-is-erlang-used-and-why

Answer (score 2):

Many of the functional languages were designed for use in high-uptime systems. Erlang, for example, is the language behind the logic of most of our cell phone carrier systems (those built on Ericsson nodes, at least). Those systems are expected to provide very high levels of availability (we're talking Nine Nines, 99.9999999% uptime; that's something like 30 *milliseconds* per year of allowable downtime) while at the same time remaining modular and highly scalable. You do that with some of the features built into many functional languages, like hot-swappable code (no need to recompile DLLs and restart the system; just put the new package in there and the next call into that package will be with the new code).

Apart from that, many ideas in computing are most easily expressed functionally. Functional programming is inherently recursive and highly parallelizable, so tasks that are best designed in such ways lend themselves well to functional languages. Parallelization in particular is becoming more and more important as the power of a CPU is being increased by adding execution units to the chip instead of increasing clocks. File processing and other ETL tasks are definable functionally and benefit greatly from throwing more threads at the problem.

Comment: I don't see how anything from the first paragraph is related to functional programming.

Comment: Not so much the concept of functional programming, but the languages and runtimes themselves. I'm sure you could put hot-swapping into the .NET runtime including C#, but it simply isn't there. Part of the difference is inherent in the requirements of a functional runtime, and is thus inherent in functional programming.

Comment: Nine Nines is 30 milliseconds a year of downtime

Comment: @Jarrod: He wrote six nines.

Comment: @Jonas, And **I** wrote Nine Nines, that is what quoted in all the books and references to Ericsson's requirements.

Comment: Immutable state models make hot-code swapping almost trivial, vs trying to do that with Java or .Net next to impossible or so restrictive to not be useful.

Comment: @Jarrod: With no restarts and no upgrades, that isn't hard: http://www.erlang-factory.com/upload/presentations/243/ErlangFactorySFBay2010-MatsCronqvist.pdf

Answer (score 1):

Functional programming is superior across the board. I have not found a case where a functional programming language, or a more functional style in an imperative language, is a bad solution to a problem.

It’s simply a lot easier to get things done when the language is more expressive. It’s not about terseness—though that is a side effect—but rather about being able to understand and reason about more of your program at once. In a functional language, you don’t always have to write a description of *how to compute* what you want—you can write a description of what you *actually* want.

Using a functional programming language encourages you to think about your program in terms of data flow and computation, rather than state and mutation. It’s so much easier to *solve problems* functionally. And isn’t solving problems exactly what programmers are supposed to do?

Comment: "Functional programming is superior across the board." - Can you recommend any good **functional** GUI Framework? e.g. a GUI frameworks that uses immutable datastructures.

Comment: @Jonas: There's tons of them to build great static GUIs with.

Comment: @Jonas: Disregarding whatever you might mean by “good”, the fact that no one has written a framework you consider good does not mean that such a framework cannot be written, nor does it mean that a framework does not exist that’s good by other standards than yours. Besides, there are [too many GUI libraries for Haskell](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Applications_and_libraries/GUI_libraries).

Comment: @back2dos list one ton of haskell gui's. Assuming a typical 2 TB harddrive weighs 5 lb, and assume that a library takes 1 GB [1000 MB] (which it shouldn't), we can then say a ton of hard drives is 800 TB, which would mean there should be at least 800,000 haskell gui libraries. Plus you said tons, not just a ton.

Comment: @back2dos, more realistically, HDD=3.5 lb, Capacity: 1818 GB (1024 MB). Ton capacity: 1,013 TB (1024 GB). Library: 35 MB (1024 KB). Total Count of Libraries in ton: 30,371,196. All numbers rounded down to nearest whole part.

Comment: @Malfist: A true haskell master will write his programs on paper, as well as the formal proof of their correctness ;)

Comment: @Jonas, google for "functional reactive programming".

Comment: @SK-logic: I have read about it before, but still haven't found a good framework that is comparable to the imperative ones I have used.

Comment: @JonPurdy: From your link: "all are more or less incomplete" - I don't see how functional programming is superior imperative programming for GUI stuff then..

Comment: @Jonas: So lack of libraries discounts a whole paradigm. I don’t want to live on this planet anymore.

Comment: @JonPurdy: Well you apparently want to live on a planet where everything is all or nothing. Where a "whole paradigm" is either "superior across the board" or worthless.

Comment: @back2dos: There is nothing in my answer or comments that says that, but okay.

Comment: @JonPurdy: Actually, there is. And you can either think about that, or deny it and continue being unhappy with the planet you live on. But I will leave that up to you ;)

Comment: Check out elmlang, FRP for the browser.

Comment: @jonas, check out http://elm-lang.org/ for a functional approach to web GUI programming