# Where are functional languages used?

Tags: functional-programming, haskell, lisp, erlang

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Functional Programming in Commercial Software](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/76151/functional-programming-in-commercial-software)
>   [Which problems domains are more suited  to functional programming solutions](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/113763/which-problems-domains-are-more-suited-to-functional-programming-solutions)

I just wonder where do functional programming languages are used? Might be some good examples? Like rocket science or telecommunications?

Comment: See also [Non-OOP languages advantages and good uses](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/125649/non-oop-languages-advantages-and-good-uses) and [For what common problems is functional programming not a good fit?](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/10865/for-what-common-problems-is-functional-programming-not-a-good-fit)

Comment: In your spreadsheet application, for example. Or in your XSLT processor. Or in your C++ templates.

Answer (score 3):

Well, here's a list of projects using Erlang:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erlang_%28programming_language%29#Projects%5Fusing%5FErlang

The world doesn't revolve around building apps for tablets and mobile phones ;)

Usually functional languages are used when there is a need for a very high degree of abstraction, parallelism and scalability. This doesn't mean you cannot write code with these properties using any other language (non-functional), but the absence of side-effects on a purely functional language helps in these scenarios.

Erlang is a great example of this, since it was built from scratch to address problems that were "embarrassingly parelizable".

Also, even a language like Javascript can be used in a purely functional form, although it does let you mess up that model quite badly.

There is also Scala, that lets you program in a mix between functional (the preferred way), and procedural style. Scala is used, for instance, on the Twitter middleware layer to handle the absurd level of concurrency that they deal with.

Comment: The world doesn't revolve around building apps for tablets and mobile phones - yea, that's why I am asking :)

Comment: My personal favorite usage of Functional languages is simply to force you to think in another paradigm. I usually code in Java and Python, but I like playing around with Erlang and Scala a lot. It helps you look at problems in a new way, even in other languages.

Answer (score 3):

- Jane Street uses [OCaml](https://web.archive.org/web/20130114191915/http://janestreet.com/technology/ocaml.php) for trading.
- Since the functional programming language [ML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ML_(programming_language)) was created for theorm proving: [automated theorm proving](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automated_theorem_proving) and [proof assistants](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof_assistant)
- While it is not required, it is common to find [AI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Artificial_intelligence) programs written in functional langauges.
- Writing games for the [XBOX](https://web.archive.org/web/20150919081233/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dsyme/archive/2006/12/12/writing-xbox-360-games-with-f-and-xna-game-studio-express-courtesy-of-jack-palevich.aspx).