# What are the types of tasks for which Functional Programming paradigm really wins over imperative one?

Tags: c#, functional-programming, f#, imperative-programming, imperative-languages

During its evolution C# gradually gets more and more features which belong to functional paradigm.

Subjectively these features allow (at least me) to be more productive, fluent and write maintainable and readable code (well.. I thins so).

But I'm curious whether some **rigorous proofs** (not just testimonials) exist that for some particular task functional paradigm shines comparing to imperative one.

I've heard many times about thread safety due data immutability, but are there more examples?

A friend of mine just asked me:

> Imagine that C# and F# developers are payed equally and can be easily
>   hired. For projects of which type would you clearly vote for F#?

Sure, it is not an 'either or' dichotomy, nevertheless it would be nice to have a kind of decision tree for choosing from functional or imperative. Especially for corner cases when there is clearly a winner.

Comment: [Why do 'some examples' and 'list of things' questions get closed?](http://meta.softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/7538/31260)

Comment: http://worrydream.com/refs/Hughes-WhyFunctionalProgrammingMatters.pdf

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Which problems domains are more suited  to functional programming solutions](http://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/113763/which-problems-domains-are-more-suited-to-functional-programming-solutions)

Comment: @gnat >nice to have a kind of decision tree for choosing from functional or imperative.
I doubt it is a 'list of things' question. Really, we don't toss a coin - at least we should not - when we select tools.

Comment: Functional or imperative is not an either/or decision, even in the same project or the same programming language.  You can write in a functional programming style in any programming language using imperative constructs, and many otherwise imperative languages have first-class functional elements built into them.  You can have object-oriented programs that slip into functional style where it is useful to do so (in those languages that support functional elements).

Comment: @RobertHarvey So, what is the point of the comment? =) To my mind, it just repeats what I've written at the bottom of the question. And they do have fist-class functional elements  probably because it has some good reason which is not just a matter of taste. Software Development, if I am not mistaken, is an engineering. Hence, there must be formal justification. Btw, thanks for the link.

Comment: No, there's no formal justification.  Programmers nowadays always seem to be looking for some authority to tell them that their approach is the "correct" one, but the reality is that there is almost always more than one way to approach a problem, and each way has its tradeoffs.  You use the approach that most effectively satisfies your specific requirements.

Comment: So the way you decide is you evaluate each technique on its features, and see how those feature apply to your specific problem.  Functional programming offers immutability, referential transparency, easier concurrency, among other things.  You use it when you need the additional features that it provides.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Why only 'nowadays'? Always.=)  Otherwise, the only thing we are left with is our experience. Trade-offs should be quantified as well. No measure - no estimation.

Comment: Lisp is not the purest functional programming language around, but this may be interesting: http://www.flownet.com/gat/papers/lisp-java.pdf

Comment: There are no 'rigorous proofs' at all when it comes to software development, because we [can't measure productivity](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/CannotMeasureProductivity.html).

Comment: @MarkSeemann First, `WeCannot != ItIsImpossible`. Actually, the metrics itself must be correct. That's in its own requires a proof. Ok, let's put you in fMRI device and make you solve same tasks in different languages and paradigms. Let's now take a thousand of not devs with similar IQ, train them as equally as possible and do the same, but shuffle the order of languages each time to avoid effect of training. Are we going to see some consistency in mental load for pairs (language-task) or (paradigm-task). Will we have clearly separable clusters? May be yes, may be no. But if we do see ....

Comment: @MarkSeemann: Fowler says  "I assert that any true measure of software development productivity must be based on delivered business value." Now, delivering business value means to produce something that can be sold. Finding out what has a business value is the task of managers and marketing people. The task of a programmer is to write a program that solves a given problem, regardless of business value. You can measure productivity by letting several programmers solve the same problem (or a set of problems) and see who is faster.

Comment: @MarkSeemann Offtopic: By the way, Mark, do you notice the sad irony of the situation? =) Without formalism we are in a state of a never ending pointing at gurus as authorities. In the 'argue' of Ptolemy and Copernicus/Galileo it is the scientific method who finally won ;)

Comment: @Giorgio - If programmers don't understand the business value, they may not understand the domain or the users very well either. This just sets you up for being micromanaged as if you're working on an assembly line. Good programmers get paid for the code they write, great programmers also get paid for the code they don't write.

Comment: @JeffO: The fact that the same person can be a programmer and an analyst or business expert does not affect my reasoning: once the business person (it may be the same person doing the coding) has decided what should be implemented, you have a specific problem to solve. Different programmers can be faster or slower at implementing the same functionality. Different programming languages, tools, operating system, etc can provide better or poorer support for the implementation.

Comment: @Giorgio - I'm just talking about having some semblance of what is going on in the business. Too many developers have zero understanding of their company's products customers or where the software they build fits into the bigger picture. What is worse, they don't care and I just think that is a mistake.